# Questions about definitions of tangent space

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If we let $S$ be a unit sphere, $S = \{p \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid \|P\| = 1\}$. There are at least two definitions for the tangent space to $S$ at a point $p$ of $S$.

1. The set of vectors perpendicular to the "radius vector" to $p$.
2. The kernel of the covector (linear function) $Df(p)$ where $f$ is the function $f(p)= \|P\|^2$.

I proved $2$, how do I show that $1$ gives the same result?

Sorry about the notation.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p=\langle a,b,c \rangle$. From the formula $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ one obtains 
$$Df(p)\langle x,y,z \rangle = 2ax + 2by + 2cz = 2 \langle a,b,c\rangle \cdot \langle x,y,z\rangle = 2 p \cdot \langle x,y,z \rangle
$$
So the kernel of $Df(p)$ is the space perpendicular to $p$.